# Use slug when possiable instead of ID

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say users can create posts on my website and only later down the road after the post is created the slug column will be set until that use the post ID to retrieve/edit/show.. posts but when the slug is set use the slug.

```php
route('posts.edit', $post) // slug is not set /posts/1/edit
route('posts.edit', $post) // slug is set /posts/slug/edit
```

I added `resolveRouteBinding()` to my post model removed `$this->getRouteKeyName()` and replaced it with `(is_numeric($value) ? 'id' : 'slug')` so it can retrieve posts by id if the value is numeric otherwise it will assume it is a slug.

```php
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    return $this->where($field ?? (is_numeric($value) ? 'id' : 'slug'), $value)->first();
}
```

How would I make Laravel use the slug when it is finally set? Better approach?

Answer (score -1):

I'll suggest a better approach and it involves changing everything down to how your slug is generated.

First, let me suggest a third-party library for generating slugs called [Spatie Sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable), there are others like it but this is my personal favorite for a lot of reasons.

As soon as you install it using `composer require spatie/laravel-sluggable` next is to follow the documentation to see how to integrate it into the models that need to generate the slugs (integration is very straight forward).

Next is to add the below code to every model you wish to use slug for routing:

```php
    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
```

This tells Laravel to use the slug instead of id when you call the route like this `route('posts.edit', $post)`.

You dont need this:

```php
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    return $this->where($field ?? (is_numeric($value) ? 'id' : 'slug'), $value)->first();
}
```

...anymore

The slug is generated when the resource is created so you don't have to worry about it not being available. And also you don't have to worry about uniqueness and a whole bunch of other issues that come with slugs.

To make sure there are no surprises, the slug field in your migration should look like this: `$table->string('slug')->unique();`, this way if the slug is not available upon inserting a record then MySql will
reject it, second, if it's not unique which should be the case considering its a slug, then the record will also be rejected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not solving my problem.
A post is created and inserted into the database without a slug; therefore, the post ID should be used. Once the slug is updated (which can only happen after a while), it should be used. I can't see how your answer is solving my problem or offering a suitable approach.

Comment: If that's the case then your current setup is fine, the only thing missing is a `firstOrFail` method...its important for what you doing.